# Proportion vs. portion

Tags: meaning

I already looked them up in [dictionaries](https://wikidiff.com/), but I can't understand the meanings completely.

They said:

- Proportion is a derived term of portion.
  As nouns the difference between proportion and portion is that proportion is (countable) a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount or number while portion is an allocated amount. 
  As verbs the difference between proportion and portion is that proportion is (arts) to set or render in proportion while portion is to divide into amounts, as for allocation to specific purposes.
- As nouns the difference between ratio and proportion is that ratio is a number representing a comparison between two things while proportion is (countable) a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount or number. 
  As a verb proportion is  (arts) to set or render in proportion.
- As nouns the difference between portion and ratio is that portion is portion while ratio is reason.

[image]

I summarised them as the picture above.

According to the pie graph below ([the previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471145/proportion-vs-ratio-vs-portion?noredirect=1#comment1137662_471145)), I have been told differently that the words **"ratio"** and **"proportion"** don't suit the following sentence.

> Overall, the numbers/percentages are not that very different for each _____.

[image]

However, as stated in my summary, thus **"ratio"** equals **"percentage"**, and **"proportion"** is a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount. Now they should fit the sentence, shouldn't they?

**What are the difference between:**

**1. proportion**

**2. portion**

and

**3. ratio?**

`Thank you very much :)`

Comment: I think you would find the two words "proportion" and "portion" far easier to understand if you divorced them from one another in your mind. Their etymology is clearly linked, but they are used in very different contexts. If I were you I would think of them as entirely different words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portion is interchangeable with slice/section/piece so fits your sentence.

If you're asked what proportion you'd usually answer with a quantity, fraction or percentage. So it doesn't fit your sentence, it would be like repeating yourself.

A ratio is made up of 2 or more parts e.g. 3:1

Comment: It may be annoying, but I'm really curious. In this case, the 40% is also from 40 : 25 : 35, is **percentage** considered **ratio**?

Comment: @hbtpoprock: A ***ratio*** of 3:1 means that out of every **4** (3+1) equal parts, 3 fall into the first category, and 1 into the second category. A ***percentage*** is just a "special case" for identifying how many parts out of **100** fall into the category of interest. So **40%** corresponds to the ratio **40:60** (which would normally be expressed as **2:3** after factorising).

Comment: You're saying **percentage** is a proper subset of **ratio**, that would mean the word **"ratio"** may fit the sentence too? @FumbleFingers

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proper subset". Syntactically, a ***ratio*** is different to a ***percentage***. Primarily because with a ratio you always need to specify ***two*** numbers, but with a ***percentage*** one number (the ***total*** within which some fraction / portion / proportion forms a ***part***) is always **100**, so it doesn't need to be explicitly stated. But this sort of question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: The different parts of a [pie chart are normally called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart) slices or sectors, not portions. (Sector is the geometric term.)

Answer (score 0):

1.)
( Proportion is a derived term of portion. As nouns the difference between proportion and portion is that proportion is (countable) a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount or number while portion is an allocated amount.)

- Ok, but a portion is countable too, a portion is also a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount/number and both can be allocated amounts or not allocated amounts…… So that’s unnecessary information to determine the difference between the two.

2.)
(As verbs the difference between proportion and portion is that proportion is (arts) to set or render in proportion while portion is to divide into amounts, as for allocation to specific purposes.)

- Using the above arts example: The portions need to be set or rendered, so again they’re interchangeable. As for portions being divided into amounts, as for allocation to specific purposes, proportion also can be. Example: “Maximowiczfinds that 40% of the plants of Manchuria are common to Europe and Asia, but the proportion falls sharply to 16% in the case of Japan.” Or “The alkyl derivatives may be obtained by heating phenol with one molecular proportion of a caustic alkali and of an alkyl iodide.” So they’re still interchangeable.

3.)
(As nouns the difference between ratio and proportion is that ratio is a number representing a comparison between two things while proportion is (countable) a quantity of something that is part of the whole amount or number. As a verb proportion is (arts) to set or render in proportion.
As nouns the difference between portion and ratio is that portion is portion while ratio is reason.)

- Repetitive information, unnecessary for distinguishing differences.

*HERE IS THE DIFFERENCE….

- If you compare the definitions you’ll find that proportions are harmonious in relation to parts to each other or to the whole : BALANCE, SYMMETRY (proper or equal share). Portions can be harmonious, balanced, and/or symmetrical but are not required to be, according to how it’s defined. If you draw a potato and it’s taller than a skyscraper, it’s out of proportion. If you draw a potato and there’s a section missing, it’s missing a portion.

Hopefully this helps someone and please let me know if you find any flaws in what I’ve written. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).